# An error occurred during the pre-login handshake SQL when using HttpWebrequest change ip

Tags: c#, sql-server

I need crawl data from some websites so I use `HttpWebrequest` to get `HTML` source and use `ServicePoint`.

However, I get an `SqlException` when I try to add data to `SQL` on other server:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake.

Comment: Which DBMS, programming language and driver are you using?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2014 and C#

Answer (score 0):

What did the trick for me is increasing the timeout on the connection string, since when connecting by vpn it took to long to establish the connection. You can do this by adding ;connection timeout = value

By default the timeout is set to 15 seconds.

Hope it helps!